# How does the Add Method from the NameObjectCollectionBase collection behave?

Tags: collections, .net-2.0

Why does the **Add** method on the **NameObjectCollectionBase** insert at index position 0?
Is there a way to insert the new item at the end of the collection?

I'm facing this problem in .Net 2.0

I'm not allowed to change the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NameObjectCollectionBase` is based on a Hashtable/Dictionary, hence it is 'unsorted' by nature.

I think you are looking for a `SortedList`.

Update: If you cannot change the class, you are out of luck. Just remember after each add/insert the 'positions' may change.